# Chat banner has strange grammar

Tags: bug, chat, grammar

When I traveled to [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com) just now, I noticed that the banner when you're not logged in says this

> Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while you're at it, check out the FAQ!

This line in particular

> please be respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users.

sounds a little strange to me. Shouldn't the word 'The' be removed?

Comment: Probably due to the use of a variable...

Comment: The Donald might disagree. (inbefore)